# what's the meaning of the word 'next' in a filename?

Tags: easeljs

For example: easeljs-NEXT.js
I sense that the NEXT in caps has meaning, but don't know what.
I've tried searching on Bing, for example "what does NEXT mean in a filename".
Also tried a similar search here in stackoverflow with no result.

Comment: More context would help. What kind of meaning do you have in mind, i.e., meaning to what? Meaning to the operating system? (I'd venture to rule that out.) Meaning to JavaScript? Meaning to the programmer? What makes you think it has a specific universal meaning? What prompts you to ask the question or what is the broader question?

Comment: Meaning to the programmer/API customer-user. This appears to be some kind of file-naming convention used by the EaselJS team. The file names appear in their EaselJS version 1.0.0 drop. I think I've seen this convention used before. Are they trying to tell us something about a file when they do this?

Answer (score 1):

CreateJS contributor here.
The "NEXT" naming is the file convention we have chosen for the upcoming/in-progress version of CreateJS libraries. Typically, we commit changes/fixes over a period of time, and then *eventually* tag a new version that gets put on the CDN and (ideally/eventually) included in an updated version of Adobe Animate.

Due to our testing process, and inter-reliance across libraries (Preload, Sound, Easel, Tween), we are pretty conservative when it comes to making official builds. This is our way of making sure there are easy-to-use, compiled builds in GitHub with the latest features, fixes, and documentation. They aren't "official releases", as they might not play well with other content.

**Releases:**

```
easeljs.js (with comments and whitepace, good for testing)
easeljs.min.js (minified)
```

**Upcoming/Latest**

```
easeljs-NEXT.js
easeljs-NEXT.min.js
```

Prior to version 1.0, we used version names:

```
easeljs-0.6.2.min.js
easeljs-0.6.2.combined.js (the old testing version, not included on CDN)
```

You can also find "Combined" scripts [on the CDN](https://code.createjs.com/) (and other CDNs) that have all 4 libs included. We didn't build NEXT versions of these, since they would be prone to issues:

```
1.0.0/createjs.js
1.0.0/createjs.min.js
```

Again, before 1.0, we used a version, which for combined libs was a release date, since they actual version numbers of the libs didn't all align.

```
createjs-2015.11.26.min.js
createjs-2015.11.26.combined.js
```

We are working on improving our release schedule, so there are more official releases than in the past. Hope that provides some insight!